# Access function variables within a script

Tags: matlab, function, variables

I've created a function which takes input data and calculates/outputs several values. I've then written a script which calls this function.

Using the script, I want to:

1) Display the list of output values calculated in the function

2) Plot these values against each other on a graph

However, as the output values are in the function, I cannot find a way to display the list of output values using the script.

In the script, using >> table(x,y,yfit) gives "undefined variables" as x,y and yfit are in the function - they're not variables accessible in the script.

To then plot x,y,yfit using the function, again, these are values in the function, so I can't see how to plot them using a script.

**Is there any way I can access the output values from the function in the script?**

Function:

```
function [sumx, sum2x, sumy, sumxy, a, b, rms] = rmsLinear(data)
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
x=data(:,1);
y=data(:,2);
yfit=data(:,3);

N=length(x);
sumx=sum(x);
sum2x=sum(x.^2);
sumy=sum(y);
sumxy=sum(x.*y);

X=[N,sumx; sumx, sum2x];
Y=[sumy;sumxy];
c=X\Y;
a=c(1);
b=c(2);
rms=(1/N)*sum((y-(a+b*x)).^2);
```

Script:

```
data=importdata('linear.csv');
rmsLinear(data);
```

Comment: Please see: [mcve]. Have you defined [outputs for your function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html)?

Comment: I've edited the post

Comment: You're not assigning any of the outputs from `rmsLinear` in your script. Please read the linked documentation.

Comment: Ah, I've got it, just forgot to assign the outputs as you said. Thank you!